# how to convert a string slice to rune slice

Tags: go

how can I convert type `[]string` to `[]rune`?

I know you can do it like this:
`[]rune(strings.Join(array,""))`
 but is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would prefer not to use `strings.Join(array,"")` for this purpose because it builds one big new string I don't need.  Making a big string I don't need is not space-efficient, and depending on input and hardware it may not be time-efficient.

So instead I would iterate through the array of string values and convert each string to a rune slice, and use the built-in variadic append function to grow my slice of all rune values:

```
var allRunes []rune
for _, str := range array {
    allRunes = append(allRunes, []rune(str)...)
}
```

Comment: When you do []rune(str) does it allocate a new rune for each occurrence?